# R unicode (Arabic) output in tibble print

Tags: r, unicode, tidyverse, arabic

When trying to print a tibble containing Arabic characters, the unicode points rather than the characters are printed:

```
> test <- tibble(lat=c("a", "b"), ara=c("ا", "ب"))
> test
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  lat   ara  
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     <U+0627>    
2 b     <U+0628>
```

It is clearly not an encoding problem, because when I print only the column, it works without a problem:

```
> test$ara
[1] "ا" "ب"
```

Same problem with `print()` and  `head()`:

```
> print(test)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  lat   ara  
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     <U+0627>    
2 b     <U+0628>
> head(test)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  lat   ara 
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     <U+0627>
2 b     <U+0628>
```

Is there a way to print the Arabic as it should look inside the tibble print?

Comment: works for me, are you using Rstudio?

Comment: try running `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Arabic")`

Comment: Works for me (maybe because I can see `system code page: 65001` in  `sessionInfo()`?)